# How to get response stream after uploading a file

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I am working on a metro app. I used background uploader to upload file but my question is how I get response value after uploading it. I coded like this:

```
          BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
          uploader.SetRequestHeader("Content-Disposition", "form-data");
          uploader.SetRequestHeader("name", "userfile");
          uploader.SetRequestHeader("filename", App.ViewModel.DeviceId + ".png");
          uploader.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

          UploadOperation upload = uploader.CreateUpload(uri, file);
          await upload.StartAsync();
```

Comment: As an aside, App.ViewModel.DeviceId is Personally Identifiable Information. I'd consider using some other unique identifier.

Answer (score 7):

I came up with the following after noticing there were BytesReceived in my upload progress object.

```
async private Task<string> GetUploadResponseBody(UploadOperation operation)
{
    string responseBody = string.Empty;
    using (var response = operation.GetResultStreamAt(0))
    {
        uint size = (uint)operation.Progress.BytesReceived;
        IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(size);
        var f = await response.ReadAsync(buffer, size, InputStreamOptions.None);

            using (var dr = DataReader.FromBuffer(f))
            {
                responseBody = dr.ReadString(dr.UnconsumedBufferLength);
            }                
    }
    return responseBody;
}
```

Comment: This definatley works but from time to time we get an System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page". It seems the answer (in this case OneDrive) is not always a correct string. Did you stumble upon this and know a workaround by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

```
upload.StartAsync().Completed = UploadCompletedHandler;
```

...

```
void UploadCompletedHandler(IAsyncOperationWithProgress<TResult, TProgress> asyncInfo, 
  AsyncStatus asyncStatus)
{
  // get a response body from an asyncInfo using the asyncInfo.GetResults() method
}
```

Follow this resources:

1. [UploadOperation.StartAsync | startAsync Method (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.uploadoperation.startasync?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)
2. [IAsyncOperationWithProgress Interface (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206594.aspx)
3. [AsyncOperationWithProgressCompletedHandler Delegate (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/br206574.aspx)

Comment: I don't understand how this would allow you to get the response body?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same thing for the last few days and no luck. Finally discovered that you can not do this. You can get the "headers" of the response but there is no way of getting the "body" of the response from a BackgroundTransfer getResponseInformation() method.

Currently it's a limitation of the windows API. Hope they'll add it soon.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.responseinformation.aspx#properties

The workaround is you can add your custom header in the response. For this you need to modify your server side script. But if you don't have any control on your server side script then use a proxy script that will do the communication between your app and remote server. For my case I created a proxy script in php that communicates with the remote server and after getting the response I'm adding it into a custom header key.

Then in the app in your complete method use this:

```
function complete(e){
    var mykey = e.getResponseInformation().headers.lookup("mykey");
}
```

Hope that'll help.